# Jmeter- Access log sampler: Increase load up to 5x from orignal logs

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, access-log

For development purpose I am sole user of my application. So I used my application normally for an hour an take access logs of it via tomcat. Now I am using Jmeter to test against these logs according to [this Tutorial](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/jmeter_accesslog_sampler_step_by_step.pdf).

When I define Number of Threads=1 in Thread Group , Jmeter only process Ist request  from log.
When I define Number of Threads=2 in Thread Group , Jmeter only process Ist 2 request  from log.
When I define Number of Threads=3 in Thread Group , Jmeter only process Ist 3 request  from log.
...
...
and so on.

My motive is to double(2x) or triple(3x) or nx the load from actual load and test it. How can I define my Test Plan in order to do it.

What I need to do for one user(I guess thread), Jmeter process all logs once. For n User Jmeter create n threads which individually process whole log simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check number of iteration value so that it as a sufficient value and add a Cookie Manager.

But access log sampler is not the best way to load test an application.

Why not use jmeter proxy:

- jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: First of all thanks for response. I checked no. of iteration but still result are not as expected. There are hundred's of different REST call in application. So I guess using log sampler would be an easy approach, or is there any thing else I can do?

Comment: Why not use jmeter proxy ? http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf